# Stopping the scan

Tags: android, google-cast

My andrdoid app has suddenly stopped detecting the Chromecast. All other apps are picking it up.

The logs show:

```
12-12 23:16:24.536: D/CastMediaRouteProvider(957): in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=DiscoveryRequest{ selector=MediaRouteSelector{ controlCategories=[com.google.cast.CATEGORY_CAST, com.google.cast.CATEGORY_CAST_APP_NAME:b1f0fdaf-05be-4941-8918-d140393ab734_1] }, activeScan=true, isValid=true }
12-12 23:16:24.536: D/CastMediaRouteProvider(957): stopping the scan
```

And:

```
12-16 14:59:43.411: D/NetworkRequest(3276): performGet: http://10.0.0.18:8008/apps/b1f0fdaf-05be-xxxxx_1
12-16 14:59:43.411: D/SimpleHttpRequestImpl(3276): executing http request: GET http://10.0.0.18:8008/apps/b1f0fdaf-05be-xxxxx_1
12-16 14:59:43.418: D/NetworkTask(3276): onPostExecute result: -4
12-16 14:59:43.418: D/ApplicationSupportFilterListener(3276): Device does not support app b1f0fdaf-05be-xxxxx_1
12-16 14:59:43.434: D/SimpleHttpRequestImpl(3276): final URI: http://10.0.0.18:8008/apps/b1f0fdaf-05be-xxxxx_1
12-16 14:59:43.434: D/SimpleHttpRequestImpl(3276): status line: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

They key line is "Device does not support app [my application id]".